# Json data stored in a string type column, how to interact with it

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column of type String where json data is stored, I am not able to interact with this column.

```
    id                          active  indicators
0   617f27ad9df9b10b633d5850    True    [{'_id': '617abc32fe562a3281b4448d', 'column': 'created_at', 'indicatorId': '61088233be3a2e04a2d3d8f8', 'value': '00-00-00', 'key': '****'}, {'_id': '617abc32fe562a4441b2268e', 'column': 'hash', 'indicatorId': '61088233be3a2e04a2d3d8fc', 'value': '14fsdfsd44*', 'key': '****'}
```

The column types

```
df_raw_nps.dtypes
id                               string             
active                           boolean                        
indicators                       string                         
dtype: object
```

I'm trying to access to create new columns according to the values ​​of the fields "column" and "value" of this json.

```
d2 = pd.DataFrame([{n['column']:n['value'] for n in i}for i in df['indicators']])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
----> 1 d2 = pd.DataFrame([{n['column']:n['value'] for n in i}for i in df['indicators']])

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

The result was to be like this:

```
    id                          active  created_at  hash
0   617f27ad9df9b10b633d5850    True    00-00-00    14fsdfsd44*
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I've tried to convert the column to a json object but without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have shown that the columns contains a string (which BTW is **not** a valid Json because it uses simple quotes...), you must *literal_eval* it:

```
d2 = pd.DataFrame([{n['column']:n['value'] for n in ast.literal_eval(i)}
                   for i in df['indicators']], index = df.index)
```

From there you have just to horizontaly concat it:

```
pd.concat((df.drop(columns='indicators'), d2), axis = 1).to_string()
```

to get as expected:

```
                         id  active created_at         hash
0  617f27ad9df9b10b633d5850    True   00-00-00  14fsdfsd44*
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!!